# React + Typescript: How can I dynamically set a generic interface for a function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript

Consider the following components:

`Basic.tsx`

```js
type BasicPropertyDetails<T extends unknown> = T & {
  label: string
  id: string
}

interface Props {
  properties: BasicPropertyDetails<unknown>[]
  onPropertySelect: <T>(property: BasicPropertyDetails<T>) => void
}

const Basic = ({ properties, onPropertySelect }: Props) => { ... }
```

`Extended.tsx`

```js
export interface ExtendedPropertyDetails{
  status: string
  price: string
}

export interface Props {
  ExtraProperties: BasicPropertyDetails<ExtendedPropertyDetails>[]
  onPropertySelect: (property: BasicPropertyDetails<ExtendedPropertyDetails>) => void
}

const Extended = ({ ExtraProperties, onPropertySelect }: Props) => { 
  ...

  return (
    <Basic properties={ExtraProperties} onPropertySelect={onPropertySelect} />
  )
}
```

I need the onPropertySelect's (in `Basic.tsx`) type to equal whatever type is passed into it in `Extended.tsx`. i.e. `onPropertySelect` in Basic should know the type to use is `(property: BasicPropertyDetails<ExtendedPropertyDetails>) => void` (based on the value in `Extended.tsx`).

Note: The type of `property` inside `onPropertySelect` will have the same subtype as `BasicPropertyDetails<unknown>`

As of now I cannot get the above to work and the implementation (or the return tsx) in Extended throws an error for types not matching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `Extended.tsx`, pass type `T` to `onPropertySelect` property.

```
export interface Props {
  ExtraProperties: BasicPropertyDetails<ExtendedPropertyDetails>[]
  onPropertySelect: <ExtendedPropertyDetails>(property: BasicPropertyDetails<ExtendedPropertyDetails>) => void
}
```

Comment: You're awesome, thanks so much. Was totally stuck on this